# conditional probability having second ball red

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Two extractions are made without re-entry from an urn that has 8 Red and 12 White balls. What is the probability that the second ball is red?

Having the $\Omega = 380$, how would you solve it without adding probabilities? Or how many ways can it be solved? Also, do you find the question clear? Because I read it in an online fun quiz and it seems to me it should be more specified, for example it should mention whether two extractions are a one time event or two extractions with successions. Is that right?

Comment: Each draw has probability $\frac 8{8+12}$ of being red, since any particular ball is equally likely to be chosen in any particular draw.  Of course, if you were told the color of the first draw, that would cause you to re-estimate the probability for the second.

Comment: Should say:  the title of your post refers to "conditional probability" but you don't suggest what you are conditioning on.

Comment: @lulu my starting approach was wrong having $\Omega = 380$ and later doing permutation formula for without re entry?

Comment: You can start that way if you want..I assume you are imagining that each ball is numbered, and then you get $380$ ordered ways of drawing the two balls.  And, indeed, looking at it that way it is he case that every ball is equally likely to be drawn second.